# What to use instead of UTF-8 for Windows Live Mail

Tags: windows, email, encoding, utf-8

I have a client that receive mails from the website, in four languages: Italian, English, German, and Russian.
Everything is fine except Russian, and he is using Windows Live Mail.

Is there any ISO character set that can replace UTF-8 and support these languages?

Comment: Why do you want to replace UTF-8? AFAIK even Live Mail can handle that **if the mail headers are correct**.

Comment: Nope, Live Mail 2011 doesn't support utf-8.

Comment: You cannot possibly be serious. Do you have an official reference for that?

Comment: check it out: http://email-client.findthebest.com/compare/2-4/Thunderbird-vs-Windows-Live-Mail-2011

Comment: I'd simply call this BS. Poking around a bit there's lots of talk of using UTF-8 in Live Mail, like [this one](http://forums.techguy.org/windows-7/966147-solved-encoding-windows-live-mail.html). Even a Microsoft product cannot possibly not support UTF-8 for emails in 2011!

Comment: Yes i know, by default it shuold be supported. Anyway i always reccomend Thunderbird to avoid this type of problems. I'll try this solution from the link.

Comment: If it really doesn't support UTF-8, Windows tends to be quite fond of UTF-16.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grabbing an arbitrary email message from by inbox in Windows Live Mail 2011, displays fine:

```
...
Date: Fri, 6 Jul 2012 10:31:46 -0700
Subject: =?UTF-8?B?KEludml0YXRpb24pIENhc2FibGFuY2EgKEV2ZW50SUQ2MzgzKQ==?=
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
    boundary="--boundary_251791_d10ae85f-6531-47e3-9bd7-dc701f50b1c6"

----boundary_251791_d10ae85f-6531-47e3-9bd7-dc701f50b1c6
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

PCFET0NUWVBFIEhUTUwgUFVCTElDICItLy9XM0MvL0RURCBIVE1MIDQuMCBUcmFuc2l0aW9u
...etc
ZnQgQ29ycG9yYXRpb24KT25lIE1pY3Jvc29mdCBXYXkKUmVkbW9uZCwgV0EgOTgwNTI=
----boundary_251791_d10ae85f-6531-47e3-9bd7-dc701f50b1c6--
```

Note the prolific use of utf-8 in both the subject and the message body and the base64 encoding to avoid the message from getting mangled by email gateways.

Comment: Yes, Windows Live Mail 2011 does support UTF-8; I just installed it on Windows 7 and was able to send and receive UTF-8 messages. It doesn't use it by default, but when composing a message, go to Options, then Encoding, then More, and select UTF-8 (once you've done that, UTF-8 will appear in the Encoding menu).

Answer (score 1):

An MUA that doesn't support UTF-8? I have to echo [deceze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/476/deceze)'s comment "You cannot possibly be serious".

But if it's really true, then what you can do is break the email into a multipart/mixed MIME message, with each part of the multipart containing the text in a different language and uses a different legacy national character encoding appropriate for that language. If all of the parts are of type text/something (text/plain or text/html) and have `Content-Disposition: inline` then the second and subsequent parts shouldn't show up as attachments.

Answer (score 0):

With Windows Live Mail closed, type regedit into the start search box and press Enter. Give UAC permission if asked.

In the left-hand pane, navigate to 
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\ Windows Live Mail\Compose\Preferences\PostEditor\Autoreplace
and click on Autoreplace.

In the right-hand pane, double-click on SmartQuotes. Type 0 (figure zero) into the Value data box and click OK.

Press F5 and then close the Registry Editor window.

Launch Windows Live Mail and test.

For more details on [Windows tech support](http://www.spotageek.com/services/windows-technical-support.php) visit to http://www.spotageek.com